# Asp.net updatePanel refresh

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

HI
I have an grid inside an updatePanel. When i select a row in the grid a postback happens.
However i donot want to refresh the contents of the updatapanel. Is there anyway to stop the refresh of the contents after the postback completes

thanks

Comment: Did you setup the Buttons as Triggers within your update panel?

    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="controlName" />
    </Triggers>

Also what are you setting the UpdateMode to?

Answer (score 2):

No.  You will have to prevent the postback in the first place. Otherwise you are re-rendering the entire page, including the UpdatePanel.  If you really need the server to do some work here, you might try calling a page method instead.

Comment: can i prevent the render of update panel by using any PageRequestManager events

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you want to do at selection.

you can set Updatepanel postbackmode to Conditional instead of always.

Comment: My thoughts exactly.  You just need to make sure that in your code behind you explicitly tell that UpdatePanel when it needs to update.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, setup the AutoPostback property to false in those controls where you don't want this to happen... for example your grid.

Comment: i want the postback to happen but no the refresh of the update panel

Comment: Ok, have you tried surrounding only the grid with the UpdatePanel... leaving out the rest of the controls in your page? In your original question you said: "However i donot want to refresh the contents of the updatapanel" I am assuming you are talking about other controls in that page. If so, just leave them out of the UpdatePanel.

Comment: The grid is the only control in the updatePanel. The grid is firing the event that is causing the postback.